# How to properly use refresh token on different devices?

Tags: jwt, authorization

After successful authorization on the client, two tokens are saved in cookies, one of them is access the other is refresh, when the access token expires, the client sends a refresh and the server issues two new tokens to the client, the point is, the fact is that if the user logs in from another device, for example, from a phone , then the refresh token on the first device will already be invalid. Refresh token is stored in the database table users, in the table fields: email, password, refresh_token.
That is, when authorizing on another device, the refresh_token field will be updated and on the first device, the refresh token is already invalid in the cookies. How to make it possible to use the refresh token, not only on one device? I saw that I needed to do something with the device identifier, but did not understand, I also did not understand where to get this device identifier. I would be grateful if you describe in detail how to properly organize this process.